# Asher in Genesis and Numbers

Tags: genesis, numbers

In Genesis 46:17 (NASB)

> And the sons of Asher: Imnah, Ishvah, Ishvi, Beriah, and their sister Serah. (...)

In Numbers 26:44 (NASB)

> The sons of Asher by their families: of Imnah, the family of the Imnites; of Ishvi, the family of the Ishvites; of Beriah, the family of the Beriites.

More specifically, in Genesis, Asher has four sons; in Numbers, he only has three clans.

What's the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges

> 17. Ishvi] This name, omitted in Num., is probably due to the erroneous repetition of “Ishvah.”

Another possibility is that Ishvah had no descendants.